# Why is AS Roma already qualified of the round of 32 after 4 played rounds?

Tags: rules, football, qualifying, europa-league

In the Group A of the *UEFA Europa League 2020/21*, *AS Roma* is [already qualified](https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/news/0263-10f302c79405-652d720efe6e-1000--four-teams-through-to-last-32/), but my question is **WHY**? Look at the table after 4 played rounds:

[image]

*AS Roma* has now *10 points*. When *AS Roma* loses the other two games versus *BSC Young Boys* and *CSKA-Sofia*, *Roma* remains on this *10 points*. If *BSC Young Boys* as mentioned above wins agains *AS Roma* and loss the last game versus CRF Cluj, *BSC Young Boys* remains also on *10 points*. Now, if *CRF Cluj* wins both games (versus *CSKA-Sofia* and versus *BSC Young Boys*, mentioned above), then they also have *10 points*.

So three teams (*AS Roma*, *BSC Young Boys* and *CRF Cluj*) have 10 points, but why is *AS Roma* already *qualified* of the *round of 32* **after 4 rounds**?

It can't be because of the good **goal difference** of *AS Roma*, because that can change in the last two games (many goals against and the other teams score a lot of goals).

#### **Does it depends on the direct duels?**

Then *AS Roma* won both games against *CRF Cluj*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSKA-Sofia can reach a maximum of 7 points, they cannot qualify in the hypothetical situation given. Changing it so they did would require Young Boys or CFR Cluj to miss points, so AS Roma is still assured of qualifying.

If the remaining teams all reach exactly ten points, tiebreakers effectively remove all matches involving CSKA-Sofia from the table, then recalculate the standings.

This leaves the following table, under the assumption that all further games are won by scores of 1-0 (this does not change the overall result, but simplifies the goals for/against/difference calculation).

1. CS Roma, 9 points, +9 -3 = +6
2. Young Boys, 4 points, +3 -4 = -1
3. CFR Cluj, 4 points, +3 -8 = -5

Thus, even in the worst case where Roma loses their remaining games and the other teams get the best possible outcomes, AS Roma is qualified first in the group.

Comment: In the **event of a tie**, only the games among the teams with the *same number of points* are counted and the points are *deducted* from the other teams that have more or fewer points. **So the direct duels in the event of a tie count as I suspected.**

Comment: No, it is not the direct duels, except in the trivial case of only two teams being tied. It is the overall results among **all** tied teams. Team X could lose both games to Team Y, but Team X may still qualify first while Team Y is knocked out.